smartlead automation restAPI
I badly need some help with using Airtable and SmartLead. How can I utilize the SmartLead API to send email replies with attachments from Airtable to a lead in SmartLead? Thank you all for your help. I attempted to send the file attachment on Airtable, but it requires access.
I tried to send by creating a script in airtable to send reply email to lead but the attachement requires permission to be openned.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
